# How to convert es5 require to es6 import

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I’m using `webpack` and `svg-url-loader` to load an SVG file into my react app. The important part though is that I want to transform this ES5 require into an ES6 import. Here is the require:

```
require('!!svg-url-loader?noquotes!../images/mustachio.svg')
```

and I came up with this import statement:

```
import mustachio from '!!svg-url-loader?noquotes!../images/mustachio.svg'
```

But isn’t there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by cleaner? There is no cleaner import than `import abc from "xyz"`. The format of the module string is determined by your module loader, not by the es6 import.

Comment: Where does `mustachio` come from? There's no variable in your ES5 require.

Comment: It’s just how it works. Anyway, I figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use default webpack require with

```js
require('!!svg-url-loader?noquotes!../images/mustachio.svg')
```

or you should add svg-url-loader to your webpack config;

```js
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.svg/,
            use: { loader: 'svg-url-loader', options: {noquotes: true}}
        }]
    }
}
```

and now you can use

```js
import mustachio from './../images/mustachio.svg';
```

Comment: Thank you! I had it like that before but it wasn’t working because I wasn’t using the `noquotes` option. Should I delete my question?

Answer (score 0):

Webpack loader is probably what you want.  If not aliases may also help.

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

For example:  A loader config in your webpack config may look like this...

```js
loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'},
      { test: /\.less$/, loader: 'style-loader!css!less' },
      { test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=css/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.woff$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=css/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.woff2$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff2&name=css/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.[ot]tf$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=css/[name].[ext]' },
      { test: /\.eot$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/vnd.ms-fontobject&name=css/[name].[ext]' },
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query:
        {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['transform-runtime', 'transform-decorators-legacy']
        }
      }
    ]
```

This avoids having to specify your loader on each require or import.